# Create a function that returns true, false or a string based on the input

Tags: javascript

On codeacademy if i have trouble finding an answer to this requirement:

> [Create a function that returns true if the number passed is even and false otherwise]
>
> Add an else if branch to your existing if/else statement.
>
> If the number put into the function is not a number at all, ... the function should return a string that tells
>   the user that their input isn't a number.

That's what I did:

```
function write (x) {
    document.write(x);
}

function isEven (number) 
{
    // Your code goes here!        
   if (number %2==0)
   {      
    return "yes" 
   } else if(isNaN(number)){         
      return "not"      
   };
};

write(isEven("Hi"));
```

Comment: "Add an else if branch to your existing if/else statement. If the number put into the function is not a number at all, instead of return true; or return false;, the function should return a string that tells the user that their input isn't a number. (This string can say whatever you like.)" -- that's what you need to do. Nothing about even or odd numbers

Comment: see the code below! that will pass the test for you. Do you understand what is going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand it correctly you want a function that returns true if the number is even, false if the number is odd and an error-string if a NaN value is received.

I would put the isNaN function first since javascript can't perform the modulo calculations if the variable has a NaN value.

```
function isEven(number) {
  if(isNaN(number)){
    return "Error: not a number";

  } else if(number %2 == 0){
    return true; 

  } else {
    return false;
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var isEven = function(number) {
  if(number%2==0){
    return true
  }else if(isNaN(number)){
    return "its a string not a number"
  }else{
    return false
  }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var isEven = function(number) {
  // Your code goes here!
    if(isNaN(number)){
        return "ain't a number";
    }
    else if(number % 2 === 0){
        return true; 
    }
    else if(number % 2 !== 0){
        return false;
    }

};
```

[Here is a jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zhncbytc/1/) demonstrating the code